# Update previous row, get value from other row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm very new with T-SQL and I need some help. I have a `table1`. How I can do this process?
Should I use nested cursor or what? Need an advice on this.

Pls refer pic here -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHYIg.gif

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @get_invckey datetime;
SET @get_invckey = '2013-04-09 13:30:43.537'

UPDATE table1
SET RUNTIME = @get_invckey
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DCREPORTTIME
    FROM table1
    WHERE
        LOCATIONAME = 'MYQ01_PRNT_A_SP3'
        AND EVENT LIKE '%RUN%'
    ) newdata
WHERE
   LOCATIONAME = 'MYQ01_PRNT_A_SP3'
   AND EVENT = 'MACHINE B STOPPED'
```

Comment: What is the table key?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @adrianm : dont have any PKey

Answer (score 0):

Not complete answer, for you question is not complex enough.

Just quick and simple example how this could be achieved.

Some sample data

```
DECLARE @Table table
(   dcreporttime datetime, event_name varchar(55))


insert INTO @Table
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:34:01', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:34:19', 'STOPPED'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:34:29', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:34:39', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:35:19', 'STOPPED'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:35:29', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:35:39', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:36:19', 'RUNNING'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:37:19', 'STOPPED'
union
SELECT '2013-04-09 13:37:39', 'RUNNING'
```

And the query. It uses CTE (Common Table Expression) and Ranking functions:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER by dcreporttime) as RankN, *
FROM @Table
)
select a.dcreporttime, a.event_name,  a.dcreporttime, b.dcreporttime, DATEDIFF(ms, a.dcreporttime, b.dcreporttime) as runtime
from cte a 
            -- shift by Rank to compare with previous row
    join cte b on a.RankN = b.RankN + 1
```

This simply you get time since previous event. I hope this could point you to solution. If don't, please be more specific in what you need :)

Comment: No,this update every row for [RUNTIME]. I need to update only which row [EVENT] = 'RUNNING'

Comment: use condition then... `CASE WHEN EVENT='RUNNING' then datediff(...) ELSE null END`

Comment: ;with cte as ( SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER by dcreporttime) as RankN, * FROM @Table ) select a.dcreporttime, a.EVENT, a.dcreporttime, b.dcreporttime, CASE WHEN a.EVENT like '%STOP%' then datediff(ms, a.dcreporttime, b.dcreporttime) ELSE null END as runtime from cte a -- shift by Rank to compare with previous row join cte b on a.RankN = b.RankN + 1

Comment: BUT,I'm not realy understand what it is doing? Actually from where is it [b.dcreporttime] is coming from? Next Row or? Will looking for next "running" time?

Comment: Right now, it's from another row. By shifting the whole table (RankN = RankN + 1) you have result, where in each row are both current and previous values, specifically a.dcreporttime is always current time and b.dcreporttime is time of previous event.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the view as follows:

```
create view [dbo].[cm] as

WITH cteMain
AS
(SELECT DCREPORTTIME, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DCREPORTTIME) AS rn,
RUNTIME,
[EVENT] AS EVENT

FROM
table1),
cte2 as (SELECT 
sLeg.rn,
slead.DCREPORTTIME AS leadvalue,
       sLeg.DCREPORTTIME AS lagvalue,
       m.EVENT

FROM
cteMain AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLead
ON sLead.rn = m.rn+1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLeg
ON sLeg.rn = m.rn-1) 
SELECT cte2.leadvalue, cte2.lagvalue, cte2.rn, cte2.EVENT
FROM cte2
```

Then, I revised the update query to:

```
update table1
set RUNTIME = DATEDIFF(ms, lagvalue, leadvalue)
FROM cm 
where leadvalue=table1.DCREPORTTIME
and table1.EVENT='MACHINE RUNNING'
```

I used the first three rows of yours as sample data and this is what I see after the UPDATE:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for? I realize, by the way, that this can all be done without a view, but, I found this to be easier to work with, as far as taking on the problem step by step.

I based my query on a query I found at the following link:

[Query to simulate Lead function in SQL Server 2008](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/)

See SQLFiddle at: [SQLFiddle for Update previous row, get value from other row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d284c/1)

Comment: This is not the output i'm look for. I just want to get the [DCREPORTTIME] from next row  to update to [RUNTIME] WHERE EVENT like '%STOP%'.